# Thumbnail images for Documents and folders- Google Drive iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

How can I get the thumbnail images for documents or folders in Google Drive api? For image type contents, I am able to retrieve from thumbnailLink property of GTLDriveFile. But if the GTLDriveFile is of type folder or document, thumbnailLink is nil. Is there any way to retrieve thumbnail images in this case?